# Optimising Expo build:web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-web

I have built an application in React Native for iOS and Android but I'd also like to make available via a web app. It all works great but the performance on the web app is a problem.

The file size build is 2.02MB. Is there a way to optimise this without impacting my native builds?

```
asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (586 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
 ./fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf (665 KiB)
 static/js/2.4f7a5c.chunk.js (2.02 MiB)

entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (586 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
 app (2.11 MiB)
     static/js/runtime~app.4b5a04.js
     static/js/2.8f75c.chunk.js
     static/js/app.59c50.chunk.js
```

Comment: have you tried to inject react-scripts and DOM?

Comment: Some Problem. Any Idea ?

Comment: Did you finally found any optimization?

Comment: Facing the same issues. Is there any advice on how to address this?